# Unable to execute Get-NLBClusterNode remotely powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, load-balancing

I've created a small cluster of 2 win servers in a domain and another for the remote executions.

I am able to run Get-NlbClusterNode locally on each of the servers.
I can establish remote session with the 2 nodes and have all the permissions in place.
I can run Get-NlbClusterNode command remotely if only one of the servers is in the cluster, but when both are in the cluster I get:

```
 PS C:\Windows\system32> Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.10.10.9 -ScriptBlock { Get-NlbClusterNode } -credential $Creds
 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) +
 CategoryInfo : PermissionDenied:
 (Microsoft.Netwo...tNlbClusterNode:GetNlbClusterNode) [Get-NlbClusterN
 ode], UnauthorizedAccessException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Access
 denied.,Microsoft.NetworkLoadBalancingClusters.PowerShell.GetNlbClusterNode
 + PSComputerName : 10.10.10.9
```

Is this the so called powershell double hop issue? How could be this fixed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue, probably due to the way the cluster has been installed (Some details [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2192207-access-denied-when-remotely-trying-with-get-nlbclusternode).) For the future, have a script ready to perform installation so as to have reproducible steps.
In the immediate, find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849108/access-denied-when-remotely-trying-with-get-nlbclusternode) some proposed solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a know issue, and as mentioned above it is a good practice to have a script perform the installation. Anyway I ended up using:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class MicrosoftNLB_Node -computername $ClusterNode -namespace root\MicrosoftNLB | Select-Object __Server, statuscode
```

which gives me the result that I needed.